# Php dynamic folder creation

Tags: php

I want my php/apache site to accept requests to a folder that does not exist - when such a request comes in some php code should kick in to create the folder and copy some files into it.

The site is a rudimentary chat site, the client wants users to specify a URL like this:

http://www.mysite.net/custom-chat

This would be like creating a channel. He does not want to do something I know how to do like

http://www.mysite.com/?room=custom-chat

Is this possible?

Comment: `google://mod_rewrite`

Comment: I guess you do not know the technical keywords for a Google search of your problem. But if you try hard, you should be able to get some insights. E.g.: [php url no question mark](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=php+url+no+question+mark)

Answer (score 1):

You can use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ([A-Za-z_]+) /yourscript.php?room=$1 [L,NC]
```

Requests to `yoursite.com/room-blah` will be rewritten to your script `yoursite.com/yourscript.php?room=room-blah`

Comment: Shouldn't the regular expression there have anchors at the start and end?